# Google YouTube API in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, youtube, google-client

I want to call the Google API to access YouTube lists, using the Google documentation I am referencing the script on my web page:

```
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client.js?onload=onClientLoad"></script>
<script>
  function onClientLoad() {
      alert(1);
  }
</script>
```

The onload function is never called, I am not sure what I am missing?!

I am trying to use the solution with an API KEY, but according to the documentation, I need to provide the API Key after the onClientLoad is called...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer, it was a honest mistake!

Needed to change the order of the script tags:

```
   <script>
      function onClientLoad() {
      alert(1);
      }
   </script>
   <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client.js?onload=onClientLoad"></script>
```

Comment: It would have been nice if the Google JS would have thrown an exception that "i don't find the onClientLaod function!